# How to JOIN 2 tables in MYSQL with same ID on multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, join, row

I'm having a hard time figuring this out. Hope someone can help me figure this out.

---

For example. I have a video site and in this video site I can submit video posts with the name of people who play in this video. But I don't want to add just 1 name it can be more. So i'd have a **video.php** page and in this page I can submit the video title of the video and the names of people who play in it.

table: ***post***

```
    -------------------------------------------
  -- video_id ---- video_name ----  video_cast -- 
    -------------------------------------------
       1              Vid-1           1
       2              Vid-2           2
       3              Vid-2           2
```

table: ***cast***

```
    -----------------------------------------
  -- cast_id ----  cast_name ----  cast_video -- 
    -----------------------------------------
       1              John            1
       2              Erik            2
       3              Ela             2
```

Now if i would be on my homepage and I see this new post. If I click on it. It will send the **video_id** information in the header so I can fetch it from the **video.php**.

page: ***video.php***

```
<?php   

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $result = mysql_query
    ("
        SELECT * 
        FROM post 
        LEFT JOIN cast 
        ON post.video_cast = cast.cast_video
        WHERE video_id='$id' 
    ");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo ' 
                   <h1>'.$row['video_name'].'</h1> 
                   starring: '.$row['cast_name'].
                 ';                   
    }
?>
```

Now how would I be able to show the **video_name** and all the **cast_name** that are associated with the video. The JOIN code I use can only show 1 name out of the table. Anybody know how I could fetch the other remaining name(s)?

Answer (score 3):

You can list the names in one row with [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
 SELECT video_name, group_concat(cast_name) cast
 FROM post 
 LEFT JOIN cast ON post.video_cast = cast.cast_video
 WHERE video_id='$id' 
 group by video_name
```

Comment: could you please explain me this group_concat?
i'm going to try it out right now.

Comment: You can use it if you group by a column. All data for a unique value of the grouped column can be put together in a comma perated list. See the Link in my updated answer.

Comment: it doesn't work

you see I have other stuff in the table post too, like video descript (video_desc) and video_src which contains an iframe embed of the video

how would i get these to show too?

Comment: Please specify in your question exactly what data you want being returned and how. Thanks.