# how to join 3 table without repeating the id?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have 3 tables: te_event, te_venue, te_category.

te_event table has columns: `categoryID, venueID, event description, title, date, price.`

te_venue table has columns:`venueID, venueName and location.`

te_category has columns: `catID and catDesc.`

here is my query

```
SELECT *
FROM   te_events
INNER JOIN te_venue
        ON te_events.venueid = te_venue.venueid
INNER JOIN te_category
        ON te_events.catid = te_category.catid
```

but it show up like this by reapeating the ID

`eventID | eventTitle |  eventDescription |venueID | catID|  eventStartDate |eventEndDate |eventPrice | venueID | venueName |  location|  catID | catDesc`

Comment: Joining can cause a set of values in one table to repeated if a record match more than one time.  Using `DISTINCT` _might_ give you what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to JOIN 2 tables in MYSQL with same ID on multiple rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103551/how-to-join-2-tables-in-mysql-with-same-id-on-multiple-rows)

Comment: Provide sample data from each table, the data that are getting and your expected result

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT e.event_description, e.title,e.date,e.price,v.venueName,v.location,c.catDesc
     FROM te_events e 
     INNER JOIN te_venue v ON e.venueID  = v.venueID 
     INNER JOIN te_category c ON e.catID = c.catID
```

See my result below

[image]

Comment: it should be like SELECT te_events.eventID , te_venue.venueName, te_category.catDesc FROM te_events  
                 INNER JOIN te_venue ON te_events.venueID = te_venue.venueName 
                 INNER JOIN te_category  ON te_events.catID = te_category.catID;
but it do not return anything

Comment: are u getting any exception or not getting any result?

Answer (score 1):

> **Why not select only the Columns You need? For example:**

```
     SELECT  E.eventID, E.eventTitle, E.eventDescription,
             E.eventStartDate, E.eventEndDate, E.eventPrice
             E.catID, V.venueID, V.venueName, V.location
             FROM te_events AS E
             INNER JOIN te_venue AS V ON E.venueID = V.venueID 
             INNER JOIN te_category AS C ON E.catID = C.catID
```

It may be a bit longer but it may still most likely give you the result you expected.

Cheers & Good-luck.

Comment: Longer in what?

Comment: @alirakiyan   **Typing all those Field-Names like above may be a bit Longer than just typing `SELECT *`**  That's what was meant in that sentence **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.categoryID,t1.venueID,t1.eventDescription,t1.title,t1.date,t1.price,t2.venueName, t2.location, t3.catDesc FROM te_events AS t1
                 INNER JOIN te_venue AS t2 ON te_events.venueID = te_venue.venueID 
                 INNER JOIN te_category AS t3 ON te_events.catID = te_category.catID
```

*I hope it helps*